# Lambda.Unknown not retrying lambda execution in Step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am executing a Java lambda in a step function.  I am throwing any exceptions in lambda code as RuntimeExceptions. I am hoping to retry the lambda execution via below code on getting any Runtime exception(since https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html says any unhandled lambda errors come up as Lambda.Unknown). However, this does not retry lambda execution on failure.:

```
    "STATE_NAME": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:*:$LATEST",
        "Payload": {
          ...
        }
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.Unknown"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
```

What does work though is if i replace Error condition with States.ALL. However this also would include invalid permissions, state timeouts etc. on which i do Not want to Retry the lambda execution. Is there something i am missing here?

Comment: Is not States.TaskFailed working in your case ?

Comment: It might, i am curious to know why Lambda.unknown is not working.

Comment: Do you know why and where the code fails ? I guess its a different type error

Answer (score 0):

Based on AWS doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/bp-lambda-serviceexception.html)

> Unhandled errors in Lambda are reported as Lambda.Unknown in the error output. These include out-of-memory errors and function timeouts. You can match on Lambda.Unknown, States.ALL, or States.TaskFailed to handle these errors. When Lambda hits the maximum number of invocations, the error is Lambda.TooManyRequestsException. For more information about Lambda Handled and Unhandled errors, see FunctionError in the AWS Lambda Developer Guide.

If you are throwing exception in lambda code, then it will not be classified as `Lambda Unhandled errors` based on that clasifications.